How can I use multiple GitHub accounts on the same Mac device?
I have a company GitHub account and a personal GitHub account. Recently, I want to use my personal GitHub account on my company Macbook. I already have the company GitHub account set up on the company Macbook long time ago. But now I have no idea how I can switch to my personal GitHub account on some of my projects while keep using the company GitHub account on those company projects' repositories.
I want to be able to freely use both personal and company GitHub accounts on the same Macbook device.

If you use the GitHub gh command line interface there seems to be a switch command that lets you switch between accounts.

you can try below procedures:
Open terminal in Macbook
cd ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your github email" -f "my-personal-github"
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"  
ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/my-personal-github
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/my-personal-github.pub

Then login to your GitHub account and go to section "SSH and GPG Keys", click on "New SSH Key" and then add the public key just copied by the pbcopy command.
touch ~/.ssh/config

Add the following content to the file
Host github.com-personal
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-personal-github

Then, to use the new config, we clone the GitHub repo by command
git clone git@github.com-personal:[your GitHub ID]/[Your Repo ID].git
git remote add "origin" git@github.com-personal:[your GitHub ID]/[Your Repo ID].git

Hope this can help!

It works, thank you!
